# md-tabs disable keyboard navigation

Tags: html, angularjs, tabs, material-design

I'm facing an issue using md-tabs. My tabs' title are editable text (using angular-editable-text) and when I'm in editing mode I can't use left and right arrow from my keyboard and the space bar because there're used to navigate between tabs.
I don't need the keyboard navigation to change tabs but I need, at least, the space bar when I'm editing the tabs' name.

I've looked on the internet several hours and I didn't find a solution. Is there a way to do that or should I try an alternative to md-tabs ?

Regards,
Nicolas